# Is there a proper way to change the image loaded to the imageview of an inflated view?

Tags: android, imageview

I have a layout with some buttons loaded in it. Each button represents an exhibit. Clicking on a exhibit, an alertbox with an inflated view is created which contains some fields from my database, including the name of an image which then is used to be loaded with Picasso using a url. On that inflated view I have an edit button which lets me edit the fields and save them on the database. The problem is that I cannot change and then save the new image to my database.

I have tried to use 2 libraries I had found
 https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker
https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage

While both seem to get me to pick the image, the image is never loaded/saved.

I have also tried to post my issue to both the above, but I had no response back. I don't think there is need for code, as it is just an inflated view within an alertbox with an imageview and 3 textviews.

Can someone give me some help?
Thank you

EDIT: Added code on request. Only have the imagepicker library code. PickImage tries to load image either with Bitmap or URI.

```
private void exhibitalertbox(int ii){
  //Initializes the data to be shown. setText to the 3 Textviews 
Picasso.get().load("mysite/uploads/"+exhibits[ii][4]).into(exhibitphoto);
editbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
exhibitphoto.isClickable();
            exhibitphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    ImagePicker.create(MuseumActivity.this)

                            .start();

                }
            });
}
```

Then the below is what i use when i try to change the image

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (ImagePicker.shouldHandle(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // Get a list of picked images
        //List<Image> images = ImagePicker.getImages(data);
        // or get a single image only

        Image image = ImagePicker.getFirstImageOrNull(data);

        //ImageView exhibitphoto=vi.findViewById(R.id.exhibitphoto);
        Log.e("image",""+image.getPath());


        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

As of now the image variable returns data but it doesn't seem to 'add' it to the image view. I tried to 'target' the imageview and add to it, trying to pick the image from the image.getPath() but with no success. . And i still have to save the image to the database on top of that.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have written if possible?

Comment: Added, could you please check it? Thank you

Comment: Can you verify that you are getting the image object and path it is not null? Are you able to get the imageview instance from findViewById method?

Comment: Please also share the line of code that you have tried to set the picked image into the image view.